# How to simulate a sample from log skew t distribution in R

Tags: r, distributions

How I can simulate a sample from log skew t distribution with lambda equals to 0?

I didn't find any packages can do it and I'm not so in order to write a function. Can someone help me to understand how to simulate a sample from that distribution?

Comment: You can use the `rst` function in the [sn package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sn/sn.pdf).

Comment: that one is a skew t distribution, I'd like to have a log skew t distribution. At the moment I'm using rst function. Thank you so much for the comment! :)

Comment: The log-skew is not the exponential of the skew ? (as the log-normal is the exponential of the normal).

Answer (score 2):

If $U$ is uniform between 0 and 1, and if $F$ is a cumulative distribution function, then the random variable $X = F^{-1}(U)$ has cumulative distribution function $F$. This result is known as [the inverse probability integral transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). Therefore, to generate a value from your distribution, it suffices to draw $u$ from $U(0, 1)$ and to make the inverse transformation $F^{−1}(u)$.

PS: I do not know how tractable is the cdf of the log skew t distribution.